# wpf-extend toolkit

Tags: wpftoolkit

I've just learned about the extended wpf toolkits (all have the same dll names).  The first one with the msi is feb 2/10, then Aug, updated Aug, Sept, and now Nov.

Are the newer dll's supposed to override the older ones and still contain unchanged controls?

Answer (score 1):

yes you only need the latest release